# Can not start docker containers with rails react and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've been trying for several days to run my frontend and backend application with docker but without success, I would also need it to be served via nginx. Here's my current configuration, if anyone could tell me what's wrong with it, that would be great.

Project structure

```
/frontend
/backend
/nginx
docker-compose.yml
```

I can start the Dockerfile frontend with `cd frontend && docker build -t frontend . && docker run -p 2000:80 frontend` but from the root of project when i run `docker-compose up` frontend, backend and nginx exit with code 0

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - './backend:/myproject/backend'
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment: 
      - RAILS_ENV=production
      - MASTER_KEY=XXXXXXXXXX
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 4000:80
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
```

**backend/Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

RUN mkdir -p /myproject/backend

WORKDIR /myproject/backend

COPY Gemfile /myproject/backend/Gemfile

COPY Gemfile.lock /myproject/backend/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

COPY . /myproject/backend

RUN bundle exec rails db:create

RUN bundle exec rails db:migrate

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-p", "3000", "-b", "'0.0.0.0'"]
```

**frontend/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.18.3-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /myproject/frontend

COPY package.json /myproject/frontend/package.json

RUN yarn global add webpack

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.15.2-alpine

COPY --from=builder /myproject/frontend/dist /var/www

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**frontend/nginx.conf**

```
# auto detects a good number of processes to run
worker_processes auto;

#Provides the configuration file context in which the directives that affect connection processing are specified.
events {
    # Sets the maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by a worker process.
    worker_connections 8000;
    # Tells the worker to accept multiple connections at a time
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    # what times to include
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # what is the default one
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Sets the path, format, and configuration for a buffered log write
    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $upstream_addr '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    server {
        # listen on port 80
        listen 80;
        # save logs here
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;

        # where the root here
        root /var/www;
        # what file to server as index
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to redirecting to index.html
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
            expires 1M;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Javascript and CSS files
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
        location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }
}
```

**nginx/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

**nginx/default.conf**

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:80;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass        http://backend:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

}
```

`docker-compose up` **command output**

```
docker-compose up
Creating network "myproject_default" with the default driver
WARNING: Found orphan containers (yaichi) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Creating postgres ... done
Creating myproject_backend_1 ... done
Creating myproject_frontend_1 ... done
Creating myproject_nginx_1    ... done
Attaching to postgres, myproject_backend_1, myproject_frontend_1, myproject_nginx_1
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
backend_1   | ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
backend_1   | The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
nginx_1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: error: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
backend_1   | The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
myproject_frontend_1 exited with code 0
myproject_backend_1 exited with code 0
nginx_1     | 2020/08/21 07:41:44 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
nginx_1     | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
postgres    |
postgres    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres    |
postgres    | 2020-08-21 07:41:44.480 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres    | 2020-08-21 07:41:44.480 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres    | 2020-08-21 07:41:44.504 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres    | 2020-08-21 07:41:44.765 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-21 07:40:56 UTC
postgres    | 2020-08-21 07:41:44.867 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
myproject_nginx_1 exited with code 1
myproject_nginx_1 exited with code 1
nginx_1     | 2020/08/21 07:41:47 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
nginx_1     | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
myproject_nginx_1 exited with code 1
myproject_nginx_1 exited with code 1
nginx_1     | 2020/08/21 07:41:51 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
nginx_1     | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
myproject_nginx_1 exited with code 1
nginx_1     | 2020/08/21 07:41:55 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
nginx_1     | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
myproject_nginx_1 exited with code 1
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping myproject_nginx_1    ... done
Stopping postgres      ... done
```

`docker-compose up --build` **output**

```
docker-compose up --build
WARNING: Found orphan containers (yaichi) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Building backend
Step 1/12 : FROM ruby:2.7.1
 ---> 958d3491c09a
Step 2/12 : RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8ae75fa12b3
Step 3/12 : RUN mkdir -p /m3/backend
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cb3b556f8ce3
Step 4/12 : WORKDIR /m3/backend
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 764b5236b91f
Step 5/12 : COPY Gemfile /m3/backend/Gemfile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d40100111945
Step 6/12 : COPY Gemfile.lock /m3/backend/Gemfile.lock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0682d5bf02f0
Step 7/12 : RUN bundle install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9615e684ebd
Step 8/12 : COPY . /m3/backend
 ---> 12ea56e4eeff
Step 9/12 : RUN bundle exec rails db:create
 ---> Running in 4e394b5ba38f
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'm3_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:50:in `rescue in postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:33:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:887:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:910:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:871:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:593:in `checkout'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:437:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1119:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:221:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:189:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:12:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:21:in `create'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:126:in `create'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:185:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:479:in `block (2 levels) in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:476:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:476:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:475:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:475:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:184:in `create_current'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:39:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the output of `docker-compose up` also, would you mind posting that?

Comment: @MarkoE I just updated my post with `docker-compose up` output

Comment: Try adding `container_name` for `frontend` and `backend` in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: @MarkoE same errors with `container_name` for frontend and backend

Comment: I just realized that the `frontend` container never comes up, (judging by the output) hence Nginx can't find it. Try maybe like this: `docker-compose up --build` and see if there are any errors during the build process.

Comment: @MarkoE I juste update my post with `--build` flag output, it sound try to build backend before db

Comment: It seems that the backend app cannot connect to PgSQL?

Comment: Yes @MarkoE That was the beginning of the problem, I was able to solve all that and I finally have a working docker-compose. Thank you very much for your help 